# "Error: Cannot find module 'less'" Node.js module loading preference/order/cache?

Tags: node.js, module, require, commonjs

Here's the situation…  So I've created a Node.js module that acts as an interface to some Node.js template engines, [Shift.js](https://github.com/viatropos/shift.js).  That is included inside another Node.js module, [Design.io](https://github.com/viatropos/design.io) (it's specified Design.io's package.json `dependencies` block).  Design.io watches files for changes.

Then you build an app and `require('design.io')`.  You also install, say, Less and Stylus into your project.

This way, when you save a `.less` or `.styl` file, a chain of methods are called:

1. `require("design.io")` gets notified of the filesystem event.  Design.io then calls
2. `require('shift').render(string, extension, callback)`.  Shift.js then calls
3. `require(moduleFor(extension)) # require("less")`.  The string is compiled.

In my app (current working directory) I have installed less and stylus:

```
npm install less stylus
```

The problem I'm having is, in *step 3* which is called from within the Shift.js module, I get errors like this:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'less'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Less.engine (/Users/viatropos/Documents/git/plugins/design.io/node_modules/shift/lib/shift/less.js:6:14)
    at Less.render (/Users/viatropos/Documents/git/plugins/design.io/node_modules/shift/lib/shift/less.js:18:21)
    at /Users/viatropos/Documents/git/plugins/design.io/node_modules/shift/lib/shift.js:69:23
    at /Users/viatropos/Documents/git/plugins/design.io/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:118:13
    at Object.forEachSeries (/Users/viatropos/Documents/git/plugins/design.io/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:134:9)
    at Object.render (/Users/viatropos/Documents/git/plugins/design.io/node_modules/shift/lib/shift.js:78:31)
```

My question is, why is this happening?  I thought that you could dynamically require libraries from a module as long as they were installed *somewhere*…  What am I missing?

The goal would be that libraries like Shift.js wouldn't have to define every single dependency in `package.json`…  For an "interface to the template engines" library, that would require too many dependencies that the app would probably never be using.

Thanks for the help, hope that was somewhat clear.

Comment: I think this might be a fix…  I have a command `design.io` I call, which ran `require('../lib/design.io/process.js')` which starts the whole watcher process.  If I change that to `require('design.io/lib/design.io/process.js')`, everything seems to load correctly.  Weird, b/c `require.main.paths` are the same in both cases.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you `npm install foo`, the `foo` module gets installed in a directory named `node_modules` in the current working directory.

When you install this `shift` library, it only looks for modules to require within *its own* `node_modules` directory, or in one of the global directories `require.resolve()` searches.

And that's the simple solution to your problem:

```
npm install -g less
```

And then the library is globally visible to all Node.js code on your computer, rather than only being visible to code in the current working directory.

Alternatively, if you only want `shift` to see it, then do something like this:

```
npm install shift
cd node_modules/shift
npm install less
```